# Calendly API returns a 401

Tags: python, api, python-requests, calendly

I want to do an API call using request of my user in Calendly like [Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOUUf.png) but I can't do it. I don't know if I need something else in my code, thanks.

```
import requests, json

api_key = 'aaaaaaaaa'
header = {
    'Authorization' : api_key
}

response = requests.get('https://api.calendly.com/users/me/', headers= header)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

I'm getting a 401 response:

```
<Response [401]> {'title': 'Unauthenticated', 'message': 'The access token is invalid'}
```

Comment: What is the response you're getting?

Comment: <Response [401]>
{'title': 'Unauthenticated', 'message': 'The access token is invalid'}

Comment: I suspect you're using the API Key (which only works with Calendly's legacy API v1) for API v2. API v2 only works with OAuth authorization flow OR Personal Access Tokens. See https://developer.calendly.com/getting-started for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to use the API Key for API v2. The API Key only works with Calendly's legacy API v1. API v2 supports the following two authorization schemes:

- OAuth authorization code flow, or
- Personal Access Tokens.

See [developer.calendly.com/getting-started](https://developer.calendly.com/getting-started) for more details.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I am using personal access token to validate. Any other potential reasons as to why my request is being rejected?

Comment: @Vic can you share a curl command or a code example? If the way you're making the call is different from what's in the original question, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: I applied the same code as above and got the same error. I also tried adding `'Content-Type': "application/json"` in the headers but without luck. I am pretty sure I am on the latest API version since I have never used any other version of the app. Thank you!

Comment: Please contact support+developer@calendly.com for further assistance. Please include your steps for obtaining a token, as well as code sample for making the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a personal token with the API v2, you need to prepend `Bearer` before your token.

Example:

```
header = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}'
}
```

Source:
https://calendly.stoplight.io/docs/api-docs/YXBpOjM5NQ-calendly-api